# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.setOnClickListener on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragment

Hola estoy siguiendo un tutorial para mostrar una animación, al hacer clic en una imagen para ello se hace uso de la librería *lottie*, el mismo código funciona perfecto en una *Activity* pero en un fragmento ocurre un error.

```
class fragment_test : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var like = false
        likeimageView.setOnClickListener {     //en esta linea marca el error
            like = likeAnimation(likeimageView, R.raw.like, like)
        }
       
    }

    private fun likeAnimation(imageView: LottieAnimationView,
                              animation: Int,
                              like: Boolean) : Boolean {
        if (!like) {
            imageView.setAnimation(animation)
            imageView.playAnimation()
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_icon)
        }
        return !like

    }
}
```

Este es el error que marca:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te marca ese error porque estás intentando acceder a un elemento del layout antes de inflar el xml. Eso funcionaría en una activity solamente si llamas `setContentView()` antes de llamar `setOnClickListener()`. Los Fragments no tienen el método `setContentView()` pero en su lugar tienen `onCreateView()`. Lo que necesitas hacer e inflar el xml ahí.
Puedes hacerlo manualmente sobrescribiendo el método:

```
class fragment_test : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
        var like = false
        likeimageView.setOnClickListener {
            like = likeAnimation(likeimageView, R.raw.like, like)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

o puedes pasar el id del layout como argumento al constructor `Fragment()` para que lo infle automaticamente. De todos modos no puedes acceder a los elementos del layout en el método `onCreate()` porque éste se ejecuta antes que el `onCreateView()`. Así que deberías mover la inicialización de las vistas al método `onViewCreated()`:

```
class fragment_test : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_test) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var like = false
        likeimageView.setOnClickListener {
            like = likeAnimation(likeimageView, R.raw.like, like)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, la explicación es muy clara gracias.